# renaming files with strange unicode names

Tags: linux, bash, rename, unicode-string

Recently I downloaded some files from a website, but their names contain strange unicode characters, which my console doesn't show them properly. Now I want to rename these files to be able to use these files, but I get the following error:

```
mv: cannot stat`FILENAME': No such file or directory
```

But I am sure that these files exist.
I wonder how I can rename these files, properly.
Any ideas?

Comment: rename to what ? eg : mv filewith_strange_char to what ?

Answer (score 2):

- Using globbing characters (like `?` or `*`): `mv *some-typeable-and-unique-substring* ...`
- Using the tab-completion of your favourite shell: your start typing `mv`, then the beginning of the filename, then you press `TAB`, and then you can enter the second parameter.

If there are other files in that directory, you might have to move them to another directory to be able to use the tab-completion or the wildcards.